# how can i change that .lua script to a keyboard key?

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(5) then
       repeat
       if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
          repeat
          MoveMouseRelative(0, 3)
          Sleep(8)
          until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
       end      
       until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
    end  
          
end
```

i would to change the  MousebuttonPressed to a keyboard key how can i do that?

Comment: Where does the script even run?

Comment: I assume it's for a logitech mouse, in which case I don't think you can work with keys. Which makes sense considering that you are working with a mouse. Maybe look into autohotkey?

Answer (score 0):

G HUB is unable to monitor usual keys (digits, letters, space) state: are they pressed/released.
The only keys G HUB can "see" are: Shift, Alt, Ctrl (selectable: left/right/any).

```
until not IsModifierPressed("lctrl")  -- left ctrl
```

G HUB can also see LED status for NumLock, ScrollLock and CapsLock (for example, `IsKeyLockOn("CapsLock")`.

G HUB can also handle press/release events of special G-keys and M-keys on a Logitech keyboard (G-keys are either left-side additional keys G1,G2,... or F1-F12 keys).